# Условие if для java

Tags: java

Есть условие у которого `PresentId==2 && petit.getLock().getRegname().contains("sp2_01")` то выходит сообщение - У Вас недостаточно прав для изменения Сообщения

Необходимо чтобы данное условие действовало только для sp3_01, а для sp2_01 чтобы не запрещало.

```
 if(petit.getPresentId() == 2 && petit.getLock().getRegname().contains("sp2_01") 
){bindingResult.rejectValue("causeId", "error.petit", "У Вас недостаточно прав для изменения Сообщения");}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте конструкцию [`if-else`](http://proglang.su/java/operator-if-else)

```
if(petit.getPresentId() == 2 && petit.getLock().getRegname().contains("sp3_01") 
){/**Действие для сп3**/}

else if(petit.getPresentId() == 2 && petit.getLock().getRegname().contains("sp2_01") 
){/**Действие для сп2**/}
else
 /**Действие для других**//
```

Comment: P.S.Если ответ помог вам, то плюсаните его, нажав на стрелочку рядом с ним, а если решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав на галочку рядом с ним.